# Grant permission to mount docker volume only in specific folders

Tags: docker

How can I configure docker-engine in such a way it only allows users to mount docker volumes (-v) in specific directories or only folders it has permission to access in host (e.g., its own home folder)?

I want to avoid things like this:

```
$ docker run -it -v /usr:/usr ubuntu bash
```

if user don't has permission to modify `/usr`.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Are multiple people creating docker containers from the same host?

Comment: There are multiple users with docker privileges (belonging to docker group) using the same server. They only have normal rights over the host, but with no -v restriction, they could virtually modify any file/folder in the system. @twoTimesAgnew

Comment: If a vm for each developer is out of the question, have you thought about having one account with docker access and every other user must ssh to connect to the containers?